# AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'get_chunck'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a huge file lazily in with the pandas get_csv function. I want to access the first 5000 elements of a specified column. But I am getting the error I mentioned in my title.

```
#fetching data 
train = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dir,"Train.csv"),iterator = True)

test = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dir,"Test.csv"),iterator = True)
```

Getting the parts of the data I need:

```
labels = np.array(train.get_chunk(5000))[:,3]
train = np.array(train.get_chunck(5000))[:,2]
test = np.array(test.get_chunk(5000))[:,2]
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-b164e8752510> in <module>()
      1 labels = np.array(train.get_chunk(5000))[:,3]
----> 2 train = np.array(train.get_chunck(5000))[:,2]
      3 test = np.array(test.get_chunk(5000))[:,2]

AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'get_chunck'
```

Apparently I am not allowed to do it like this? If not, how could I rewrite this to achieve what I am trying to achieve with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_chunck` is a spelling error!

Answer (score 2):

Try `get_chunk` instead of `get_chunck`.

Answer (score 1):

`get_chunck` is the culprit ! `get_chunk`